# SharePoint 2013 - How/Can do I edit/Personalize my view on a Shared Calendar?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, settings, edit

SharePoint 2013 - How do I edit/Personalize just my view on a Shared Calendar?
I would like to personalize my view of our shared calendar with a different color background and with a different font and different font size. Is this possible? 
I dont want to change other people's views (JUST MINE).
Can some one give me very Specific instrutions as we are still learing Sharepoint and I cant find the answer to the above anywhere in the Help section.

Answer (score 0):

I did a "10 Step Guide" to get it working.
If you still interested you can give it a try.

Just try to follow the guide and **instead of choosing the default view use the calendar view you want to modify.**

If you have problems to follow the guide, let me know. Maybe I'll do english version as well...

[10 Steps to get color calendar plus icons](https://blog.afrait.com/color-calender-and-icons-in-10-easy-steps-de/)

[image]